# Adding new line before string matching regex in linux (Jenkins)

Tags: linux, string, awk

Hi I'm trying to do some CSV manipulation before processing. Now I'm strungling with following scenario.

**Input file (no line breaks):**

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,IdleTime  1611013105559,492,REST API,200,,REST API 1-1,true,,1221,32292,492,0  1611013107054,575,DB check,200,OK,REST API 1-1,true,,177,0,575,0  1611013251449,231,DB check,null 0,"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol  )",REST API 1-1,false,Row not inserted properly.,89,0,0,0
```

**Desired output (new line before the timestamp):**

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,IdleTime  
1611013105559,492,REST API,200,,REST API 1-1,true,,1221,32292,492,0  
1611013107054,575,DB check,200,OK,REST API 1-1,true,,177,0,575,0  
1611013251449,231,DB check,null 0,"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol  )",REST API 1-1,false,Row not inserted properly.,89,0,0,0
```

**Actual output:**

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,Latency,IdleTime  
[0-9]{13},492,REST API,200,,REST API 1-1,true,,1221,32292,492,0  
[0-9]{13},575,DB check,200,OK,REST API 1-1,true,,177,0,575,0  
[0-9]{13},231,DB check,null 0,"java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol  )",REST API 1-1,false,Row not inserted properly.,89,0,0,0
```

**Using this command:**

```
awk -v patt=[0-9]{13} '$0 ~ patt {gsub(patt, "\n"patt)}1' < input.jtl > output.jtl
```

Anyone can help please?

Regards Jan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '{gsub(/[0-9]{13},[0-9]{3}/,ORS"&")} 1' Input_file > output.jtl
```

***Explanation:*** Simply globally substituting`gsub` matched regex `[0-9]{13},[0-9]{3}` value with `ORS`(new line) and with the matched value itself. `1` will print the edited/non-edited current line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a GNU `sed` like

```sh
sed -E 's/\<[0-9]{13}\>/\n&/g' input.jtl > output.jtl
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - enables POSIX ERE syntax (less escaping required)
- `\<[0-9]{13}\>` - matches a leading word boundary, thirteen digits and a trailing word boundary
- `\n&` - replaces the match with a newline and the match itself
- `g` - all occurrences on a line.

Comment: Thanks this was working on my Debian but not on our Jenkins machine for some reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use backreference use `gensub`. In your case we might do

```
awk '{print gensub(/([0-9]{13})/, "\n\\1", "g")}' input.jtl
```

Note that I enclosed `[0-9]{13}` in `()` thus making it first (and only) group which I then reference as `\\1`, `g` mean global replacement (all occurences). `gensub` does return new string rather than changing, so I `print` it. If you want to know more about `gensub` then read [String Functions docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html).